# GWT and dynamic tabs

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, uibinder, tabpanel

Is it possible to create panel with dynamic added tabs in GWT using [TabPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html) or [TabLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html).

My requirements:

First tab is not closeable and has a celltable.
When I select row in the celltable, new tab is created.
Newly created tab can be closed.
My question:

How to create this architecture in GWT using MVP style and UiBinder?

Comment: have a look here http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#add(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget, java.lang.String), you can use this method to add tabs dynamically to your `TabLayoutPanel` othe approach is to clean panel with content of your tab

Comment: Thank you, but clean panel content is not really suitable for me. I must create new tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? Even if you get some problem in GWT, you always can dive into level below to javascript and make exactly what you need.

Any panel can be dinamically changed. If it is layout panel then you can `forceLayout()` it at any moment. You can `add()` or `insert()` new items to panel and use different selfmade widgets for tabs (you have a lot of possibilities how to add or insert: `add(Widget child, Widget tab)` or `add(Widget child, SafeHtml html)`).

Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/AddingnewtabdynamicallyExtGWT.htm) how it made with ExtGWT, logic is identical but you will have to made widgets for your tabs (that can be closed and not).

Comment: Yes, there are methods **add(Widget child, Widget tab)** and **add(Widget child, SafeHtml html)**. But I'd like to know how to use them in MVP pattern, especially if View is done by UiBinder